# Fragment's onDestroyView not called on back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three Fragments in my application: Fragment A, B and C.

**Steps:**

1. I am replacing A by B and keeping A in backstack.
2. I am replacing B by C and not keeping B in backstack.
3. I am pressing back button, on pressing back button  A's onCreateView and then onStart is called (as it is
   on back stack)

The problem is Fragment C's onStop, onDestroyView etc are not called and thus Fragment A is not visible on the screen and Fragment C is visible (as it;s view is not destroyed).

Comment: why are you not adding **B->C Transaction** to backstack? any special requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is some misunderstanding of the back stack.
When you replace A with B, you put the **transaction A->B** in the back stack, not the A fragment. The back stack knows that when the user presses the back button, it will have to rollback the transaction: destroy B and recreate A. In your case, you are replacing C with B and you're pressing back button: A will be recreated and B cannot be destroyed since it doesn't exist.
Maybe you can find a solution listening for back stack events using `FragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener()`, but I don't know if it fits your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Mimmo Grottoli. You cleared my understanding up to a very good extent. Please tell me how can destroy view of C.

Comment: I wanna give you what I consider the best solution for what I understand of your project. You could create the FragmentC 'inside' the 'FragmentB' that means that you can create the FragmentC using the `getChildFragmentManager()` of FragmentB. When you press back, FragmentB can be destroyed, and since C is child of B, it will be destroyed too. Please, if you find this solution good, accept the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through dev blog
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Fragments lifecycle is affected by Activity lifecycle.

Comment: This is Fragments doc, and the question was about back stack, not Fragment or Activity lifecycle.